# nodejs console.log does not produce a output on Windows inside a funtion

Tags: node.js

I tried the following code(which is produced by corresponding Typescript code) and played with some solution in previous questions and answers. No luck, nothing is produced by the code inside the Startup() function, but works with the two bottom lines. Any idea? I was using both Nodejs 6.11.x and 8.4.x on both Windows 7sp1 and 10.

Thanks,

David

```
var Startup = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Startup() {
    }
    Startup.main = function () {
        console.log('Hello World!');
        console.warn('This is a warning!');
        return 0;
    };
    return Startup;
}());
console.log("This is log");
console.warn("Thi is warn");
//# sourceMappingURL=HelloWorld.js.map
```

Sorry, more info oh the corresponding TypeScript file

```
class Startup {
    public static main(): number {
        console.log('Hello World!');
        console.warn('This is a warning!');
        return 0;
     }
 }
 console.log("This is log");
 console.warn("Thi is warn");
```

Comment: What is your expected behavior?  If you run the above script with node I would only expect it to console.log the last two lines.

Comment: In this case, if you want ``console.log()`` which is inside of ``Startup``, you can do it using ``Startup.main()``.

Comment: @user2263572 Tanaike You are both right. It worked after adding the Startup.main().

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code

```
function Startup() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
    console.warn('This is a warning!');
        return Startup;
}
Startup();

console.log("This is log");
console.warn("Thi is warn");
```

And this is giving me output as

[image]

Hope this helps..

Comment: What I concerned is the code converted by tsc from the TypeScript file. It seems I forgot the Startup.main() at the end. Thanks anyway.